# .net Jquery CheckBox onchange event losing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have this Jquery code for my CheckBoxes:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#chk_AGVS').change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    '<%Session["chkAGVS"] = "true"; %>';

                }
                else
                {
                    '<%Session["chkAGVS"] = "false"; %>';

                }

            });
        });
```

I am creating a session variable in which I transport a value depending on the checkmark.
It's working fine and I need to transport that value for another page, but when I check the variable it is FALSE when it should be TRUE because it was checked.
I don't know what is going on, but it seems that is when it makes a refresh or something, I really don't know, I need your help guys.
I can't do this on C# because of business rules so I need to do it with Jquery, what is going on and why is my CheckBox losing the value and making my session variable FALSE.

PS. I tried adding the ViewState=True but it did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.NET tags will run on the server once when the page loads:

which will set the variable to true, then to false.

Look at the code when viewing source to see what your javascript will be running, in this case it wont be running anything and probably look like this;

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    '';

                }
                else
                {
                    '';

                }
```

You cannot call server side code like this.

You would need to post a callback to the server to change a session variable.